# Why isn't my background image scrolling on Webkit browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, background, webkit, background-image

My background image doesn't scroll in Chrome or Opera (in Windows only). When I reach the bottom of the page it jumps a couple of pixels up, when I reach the top, again a couple of pixels down. Otherwise during scrolling the image stays put. In Chrome in Ubuntu it's wroking fine. Weird...
Tried putting the image in the HTML and BODY tags.

```
body {
  background-image: url("images/flag_background_300.jpg");
  /*background must be separate from gradient, otherwise the gradient repeats vertically if background-size is set*/
  background-size: 178px 100px;
  background-attachment:scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 150px, rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.7) 400px, rgba(143, 143, 143, 0.98) 100%);
}
```

The gradient in the .wrapper scrolls fine. [See my website](http://naj-doucovanie-bratislava.sk/)

Comment: This is not very clear. Explain the problem. It looks alright on a mobile display...

Comment: Yes, on all mobile browsers and Linux desktop it's fine, it's only reproducible on webkit browsers in Windows, both Opera and Chrome. Haven't checked Safari, I don't have a Mac... Just imagine the same scrolling experince, but with the background not moving and making a jump when you reach the bottom.

Comment: I am on a Windows and using Chrome. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Interesting, I've seen it in 2 different computers already doing the above, Chrome version 43. Both with Windows 7. What version of Windows are you using?